# How to convert (20190909070000+0000) to timespan like mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss pm by using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to convert datetime "20190909070000+0000" value into **mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss pm** by using moment.js.

Kindly assist me on this.

Comment: from where are you getting date string ```20190909070000+0000``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const datetime = "20190909070000+0000";
const parsed = moment(datetime, "YYYYMMDDHHmmssZ").format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');


console.log(parsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```